# How can I upload a datasource to Tableau which is NOT saved locally?

Tags: python, tableau-api

The data is parsed in as a pandas dataframe and cannot be saved locally. The tableau_api_lib and tableauserverclient seem to only accept file paths as upload options and do not accept a string, df, or bytes as an input.

Comment: Have you tried an [`io.BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO) object?

Comment: Yes, I tried that as well. Didn't work. An alternative solution was to create a separate database and connect Tableau directly to that.